# Phonebook-style data structure in Java?

Tags: search, tree

I'm interested in knowing the data structure that a phonebook would use. One that contains objects with fields like a name string, a number string, etc. and allows searching (and partial searching, like the first few letters of the name) via ALL the fields.

What is the method that a phonebook would use? I was thinking it would be some version of a tree, but I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around efficient methods of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Array of Maps:

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> a;
// ...
a.get(i).get("name")
```

**But XML is much better:**

[org.w3c.dom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) is quite easy to use and XML is extremely simple to save to a file etc.

```
<contacts>
    <contact name="..." phone="..." />
</contacts>
```

or

```
<contacts>
    <contact>
        <name>...</name>
        <phone>...</phone>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```